# change the key value of only the first object in the array react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook with objects in an array and I want to change the value of key `test` of the first object only.

```
const [Value, setValue] = useState([{test: 0}, {test: 0}]);
```

Also, I would like to be able to change a value from one to another at the click of a button, like `toggle`. For example to get only `0` or `1` on click on one button.

Could you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a copy of the state in the callback of the set function.

Then alter index `0` with the new value and return the copy.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState([{test: 0}, {test: 0}]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setValue(p => {
            let d = [ ...p ];
            d[0].test = 420;
            return d;
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <em>{JSON.stringify(value)}</em>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

As requested, on a click event:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState([{test: 0}, {test: 0}]);
    
    const updateFirstTestValue = () => {
        setValue(p => {
            let d = [ ...p ];
            d[0].test = d[0].test + 1;
            return d;
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <button onClick={updateFirstTestValue}>Add 1 to 'test'!</button>
            <br />
            <em>{JSON.stringify(value)}</em>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

As requested, on a click event with hard-coded values:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState([{test: 0}, {test: 0}]);
    
    const updateFirstTestValue = (to) => {
        setValue(p => {
            let d = [ ...p ];
            d[0].test = to;
            return d;
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => updateFirstTestValue(0)}>Set to 0</button>
            <button onClick={() => updateFirstTestValue(1)}>Set to 1</button>
            <br />
            <em>{JSON.stringify(value)}</em>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

As requested, on a click event with toggle between 2 values

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState([{test: 0}, {test: 0}]);
    
    const toggelFirstTestValue = (to) => {
        setValue(p => {
            let d = [ ...p ];
            d[0].test = (d[0].test === 0) ? 1 : 0;
            return d;
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <button onClick={toggelFirstTestValue}>Toggle 0~1</button>
            <br />
            <em>{JSON.stringify(value)}</em>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! tell pls, could you show another example how I can do the same thing but as a toggle by click?

Comment: I;ve added a second snippet, hope that helps ;)

Comment: thanks for the second example. I meant I wanted to get 0 or 1 like toggle, but not increment :)

Comment: So a button that sets it to a hard-coded value?

Comment: Easier if you add these requirements in your OP tho ;)

Comment: Added a 3th snippet, but you could also check if the value is `0`, set to `1`, or set to `0` if the current value is `1`, up to you ;)

Comment: I added an addendum to my question! thanks, but is it possible to do this on a single button click like this `d[0].test = d[0].test === d[0].test ? 0 : 1`

Comment: We're getting there ;) Added a 4th snippet with a toggle button :D

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with [immer lib](https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer) which looks more clean and do normal array operations after that. As it under the hood creates copy of the original state and work on it.

```
import React from "react";
import { useImmer } from "use-immer";


function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useImmer ([{test: 0}, {test: 0}]);
  // Now set values as you do with normal JS operations
  setValue(draft => {
    draft[0].test = "newVal"
    draft[1].test = "anotherNewVa1";
  })
}
```

You don't need to copy with this apprach by your self, and not need to be concious if you are mistakenly using mutating method like `=[]`, `push` etc. You can here use any methods from Array objects.